# How to adjust multiple conditions in one query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

See I can pass 2 parameters to the procedure to filter my search i.e. ComplainantName `or` ComplaintSubject `or` (ComplainantName `AND` ComplaintSubject)

So can I adjust in this query which just works with **ComplainantName**?

```
@ComplainantName varchar(100), 
@ComplaitSubject varchar(MAX)

Select * from ComplaintsInfo
where ComplainantName= @ComplainantName
```

I am naive and trying to sort it.

NOTE: Both or one of them can be empty sometimes i.e. user choose to pass only ComplaintSubject so in that case ComplainantName would be `""`

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
DECLARE @ComplainantName varchar(100), 
        @ComplaitSubject varchar(MAX);

Select * 
from ComplaintsInfo
where (ComplainantName = @ComplainantName OR @ComplainantName IS NULL) 
  AND (ComplaitSubject = @ComplaitSubject OR @ComplaitSubject IS NULL);

--  @ComplainantName/Subject = '' if empty string indicates missing value
```

When you want to search only using one parameter pass second as `NULL`.
This way you can filter using:

```
╔══════════════════╦══════════════════╦═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ @ComplainantName ║ @ComplaitSubject ║                             result                              ║
╠══════════════════╬══════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ NULL             ║ NULL             ║ all                                                             ║
║ NULL             ║ val              ║ records with ComplaitSubject='val'                              ║
║ val              ║ NULL             ║ records with ComplainantName='val'                              ║
║ val1             ║ val2             ║ records with ComplaitSubject='val1' and  ComplainantName='val2' ║
╚══════════════════╩══════════════════╩═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

**EDIT:**

> I also tried this and seems working for now, Is it ok ? Select * from ComplaintsInfo where ComplainantName like '%'+ @ComplainantName +'%' AND COmplaintSubejct like '%'+@ComplaintSubject+'%'

Yes you can change   `ComplainantName = @ComplainantName` with `ComplainantName like '%'+ @ComplainantName +'%'` but you should be aware that expression starting with wildcard is nonSARGable. If it is index on that column query optimizer will skip it.

```
Select * 
from ComplaintsInfo
where (ComplainantName like '%'+@ComplainantName+'%' OR @ComplainantName IS NULL)
  AND (ComplaitSubject like '%'+@ComplaitSubject+'%' OR @ComplaitSubject IS NULL);
```

You could also consider using `FULL-TEXT INDEX` for string searching.

Comment: Ok sir thanks a lot I will try this too. I also tried this and seems working for now, Is it ok ? 

Select * from ComplaintsInfo
where ComplainantName like '%'+ @ComplainantName +'%' AND COmplaintSubejct like '%'+@ComplaintSubject+'%'

Comment: @StackyFlowy You need to handle  `NULL`/missing values. If user passes `ComplainantName=NULL` you won't get any records.